# PayPal Payment COMPLETE on a static HTML/JS website with no server backend. How to render a completed payment page?

Tags: paypal

I am building a static website using only JS HTML CSS and a touch of JQuery. I have a PayPal button that works in the PayPal sandbox and charges my mock user but I can't figure out how to change anything after payment is complete.

I would like the page to redirect to a payment complete page with the order details. Is it as simple as setting up the SANDBOX APP SETTINGS URL and custom building a page with that URL?

Comment: You might want to ready the paypal documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are using something like [this client-side integration.](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

Inside the onApprove function, in the `.then()` of you actions.order.capture, you can use `actions.redirect('otherPage.html')`

Alternatively, rather than redirecting and for more of a single page application feel you can rewrite the DOM and replace the contents of `<body>` or your main container div using jQuery.

```
$('body').html('<h2>Thanks for your order!</h2>');
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for Thank you.